# Trying to enter numbers in JOptionPane then detecting the information entered and display a certain message

Tags: input, printing, keyword, joptionpane, keyword-search

```
public class Flooring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String var = "Scored concrete, costs $3000"; 
         String v2 = "Carpeting comes with a $5000 allowance";
         String v3 = "Wood floors in the living area,\n"
                + "carpeting in the bedrooms, tile in the bath areas,\n"
                + "and a $5000 carpet allowance, totaling $10,000"; 
         double selection;
        double selection2, selection3;
        String menu2, menu3, menu;
                 menu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("This program asks the user to enter a choice of flooring for a new home.\n"
                 + "Enter the number that matches your flooring choice\n"
                 + "1:Scored concrete, costs $3000\n"
                 + "2: Carpeting comes with a $5000 allowance\n"
                 + "3: Wood floors in the living area,\n"
                 + "carpeting in the bedrooms, tile in the bath areas,\n"
                 + "and a $5000 carpet allowance, totaling $10,000");
            selection = Double.parseDouble(menu);
/**************************************************************/
//need help here
              if (selection == '1');
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose selection1  - " + var, "Flooring Selection", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                     if (selection == '2');
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose selection 2 - " + v2, "Flooring Selection", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            if (selection == '3');
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose selection 3 - " + v3, "Flooring Selection", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


    }

}
```

I need help just after command line . It does not work as i expect . I am trying to enter numbers in JOptionPane then detecting the information entered and display a certain message.

Comment: Show the output of the code and your expected output